# Python remove duplicates if 4 of 6 criterias are equal

Tags: python

I'm new to python (using 3.6) and could use some help, it would be highly appreciated! I have been trying some functions using `set()` to fix my problem, but I can't get it right. Im trying to filter duplicate `Tuples` in a long `list` if the 4 first elements are equal. The list has over 600 tuples like this.

Ex. - `[(1, 1 , 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'age')] and [(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '-', '-')]` are equal at the first 4 elements so then i want to remove `[(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '-', '-')]` from the list and keep the `tuple` with 'age'. Same with `[(1, 2, 1, '0x19', '0x11', 'odd')] and [(1, 2, 1, '0x19', '-', '-')]` the 4 first elements are equal so then i would like to remove `[(1, 2, 1, '0x19', '-', '-')]` from the list and keep the one with 'odd', but if a `tuple` does not have a duplicate I would still like it stay in the `list`. Ex `[(1, 1, 3, '0x2F', '-', '-')]` and `[(1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '-', '-')]` does not have a duplicate, so I still need them to stay in the new list.

ex List:

```
[(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '-', '-')]
[(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'age')]
[(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '-', '-')]
[(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'live')]
[(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '-', '-')]
[(1, 1, 3, '0x2F', '-', '-')]
[(1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '-', '-')]
[(1, 2, 1, '0x19', '0x11', 'odd')]
[(1, 2, 1, '0x13', '-', '-')]
[(1, 2, 1, '0x11', '-', '-')]
[(1, 2, 1, '0x05', '-', '-')]
[(1, 2, 2, '0x02', '0x04', 'tree')]
[(1, 2, 2, '0x02', '-', '-')] 
[(.....................)]
```

'-' is a temporary value I have for now (I have have not assigned anything there yet).

I have no test code to show because i have no real lead on how to do this, but i guess set() and a for loop/nested loop could be used to fix this, but i don´t know how... so I'm asking for some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To do that, I would:

- create a dictionary using a tuple of the 4 first values as key, so last inserted removes the first inserted
- to make sure that the "dashed" values come first (and are overwritten if some other values with the same key arrive in the dict), let's sort according to the "2 last values are dash" criterion
- take only the values of the dictionaries (the keys are not used anymore) and convert back to list (useful in python 3)

like this:

```
l = [(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '-', '-'),
(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'age'),
(1, 1, 1, '0x19', '-', '-'),
(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'live'),
(1, 1, 2, '0x02', '-', '-'),
(1, 1, 3, '0x2F', '-', '-'),
(1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '-', '-'),
(1, 2, 1, '0x19', '0x11', 'odd'),
(1, 2, 1, '0x13', '-', '-'),
(1, 2, 1, '0x11', '-', '-'),
(1, 2, 1, '0x05', '-', '-'),
(1, 2, 2, '0x02', '0x04', 'tree'),
(1, 2, 2, '0x02', '-', '-')]

newl = list({tuple(v[:4]):v for v in sorted(l,reverse=True,key = lambda v : all(x == '-' for x in v[4:]))}.values())

print(newl)
```

result:

```
[(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '-', '-'), (1, 1, 3, '0x2F', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x19', '0x11', 'odd'), (1, 2, 2, '0x02', '0x04', 'tree'), (1, 2, 1, '0x13', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x11', '-', '-'), (1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'age'), (1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x05', '-', '-'), (1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'live')]
```

note that if you want the list sorted, just replace `newl = list(` by `newl = sorted(` and you'll get:

```
 [(1, 1, 0, '0x1636', '-', '-'), (1, 1, 1, '0x19', '0x19', 'age'), (1, 1, 2, '0x02', '0x02', 'live'), (1, 1, 3, '0x2F', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 0, '0x1637', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x05', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x11', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x13', '-', '-'), (1, 2, 1, '0x19', '0x11', 'odd'), (1, 2, 2, '0x02', '0x04', 'tree')]
```

(a second sort looks ugly, I know, but sorting by values *and* by "dashed first" is not easy, specially when the list gets filtered by the dictionary)

Comment: i don´t get it to work and i need them to stay in the same order as before, but thanks for helping!

Comment: I simplified your input data (which wasn't valid python). I'll edit to add a "keep ordered" solution (which wasn't in your question); which will be less elegant :)

Comment: the problem is that the "-" won´t be there for long, i will soon replace it with a value so i need to sort "after the 4 first"

Comment: in that case, you just need to change sort key. But since I don't know which values you'll put in there, I can't write it.

Comment: so there is no way to sort by the 4 first?

Comment: you need that the sort makes your "dashed" values first, but I can add another criterion so it sorts by items as well. Check my edit.